# .net 8 DI GetServices<object> not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In one of my services I need to get all provided services. So I tried:

```
public ServiceConstructor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    var allServices = _serviceProvider.GetServices<object>();
```

But I always get no services returned.
If I ask for a specific service this one is returned, so there are registered services.

I even tried to inherit all my services from a single interface I am asking for instead of , but with no success.

Comment: You could register your services more than once `.AddScoped<ICommonInterface>(p => p.GetService<ISpecificInterface>())`, then `GetService<ICommonInterface>()` would return them all. (or just `ServiceConstructor(IEnumerable<ICommonInterface> ...`)

Comment: Have you registered any services of type `object`? e.g. `services.AddScoped<object>(...);` Calling `GetServices<object>` doesen't make it return everything that's convertible to `object` (which is everything). It's an exact type match only. AFAIK, there's no way to get all services from `IServiceProvider`, but if there is, that's not how to do it.

Comment: Also, what is your problem that requires you to resolve *all* services? It's not a common pattern, and there may be better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: I am not registering my services as object. The posts I found let me think GetServices<object> return all services, because this is the basetype all services inherits from... so this seems not to be the case....

Comment: At the end of the day I just need this in my SerializerService, to store the complete programstate in a JSON, to be able to load it later... I searched a lot for other pattern to do this, but I did not found any good solution.

Comment: What you have here, then, is an X/Y problem. You need to focus on the problem you originally had in the SerializerService and find a different solution. I suggest looking at `ActivatorUtilities`, but without knowing what you're doing, it's a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont' thinks get all services is a good idea, but you could try this get type names from assembly first.

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public ValuesController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {

            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public void test()
        {
            
            var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                 .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
                 .ToList();
            foreach(var type in types)
            {
                try
                {
                    var instance = serviceProvider.GetService(type);
                    if (instance != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(instance.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Test
[image]

Comment: thanky, that would do the job in my case.
But as madreflection mentioned, there would be a better solution für my problem, so I created a new question for this:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77806953/how-to-serialize-complete-programstate-in-an-app-with-dependency-injection)